# Combine 2 lists using linq and add fields for duplicate records

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two lists of a Report object

```
public class Report
{
    public string Status {get; set;}
    public string ContractNumber {get; set;}
    public int Count {get; set;}
}
```

I have two lists of those objects `List<Report> listP` and `List<Report> listE`

I need to combine those two lists, and keep only distinct values, but for duplicates, I need to update `Count` field, so the new list objects would look like this

```
new Report{
    Status = Status;
    ContractNumber = ContractNumber;
    Count = listP.Report.Count +  listE.Report.Count;
}
```

Mind that Status and Contract number are the same for both lists, if there is a duplicate.

How linq query would look like?

Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate all items from both lists, then group items by status and contract number. From each group create new report object with appropriate status and contract number, and sum of counts of all items in group:

```
var list = listP.Concat(listE)
                .GroupBy(r => new { r.Status, r.ContractNumber })
                .Select(g => new Report {
                     Status = g.Key.Status,
                     ContractNumber = g.Key.ContractNumber,
                     Count = g.Sum(r => r.Count)
                });
```

Or query syntax:

```
var list = from r in listP.Concat(listE)
           group r by new { r.Status, r.ContractNumber } into g
           select new Report {
              Status = g.Key.Status,
              ContractNumber = g.Key.ContractNumber,
              Count = g.Sum(r => r.Count)
           };
```

Comment: Thank you Sergey. Is it necessary to group by contract number and status together? I tried group by without status but then it is not possible to use it in select. I am new to linq so sorry if my question is weird.

Comment: @Macin it depends how you define distinct entities. If only ContractNumber matters, then group by ContractNumber. But in that case you should define how to get aggregated status. It can be some max value of status or anything you will define